# How to add dropdown selected data to table using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have one jquery dropdownlist box with hardcoded values as below.

```
<h2 class="form-box form-box-default">Jquery Dropdown List with Max 2 select</h2>
        <select class="limitedNumbChosen" multiple="true">
            <option value="1">Monday</option>
            <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
            <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
            <option value="4">Thursday</option>
            <option value="5">Friday</option>
            <option value="6">Saturday</option>
            <option value="7">Sunday</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="Get Values" class="submit1" id="submit1" />
        <table id="table1">
        </table>
```

I can select multiple options here. I have one button below and i also have one table. On clicking on that button i want to add selected values to table rows.
I have below script to get selected values

```
 $("#submit1").click(function () {
        {
            var selected = $('.limitedNumbChosen :selected').text();

            selected.each(function () {
                $('table1').append('<tr><td>'+$(this).val() +'</td></tr>');
            });
        }
    });
```

Here I am  able to get selected values to selected. I tried to append each value to table as above but nothing gets binded. Can someone tell me how can i bind the selected values? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:** remove the `text()`  in var selected,  and add `$('#table1')` in each function

If you need a text change with `$(this).text()` in each function

```js
$("#submit1").click(function () {
        {
            var selected = $('.limitedNumbChosen :selected');
          selected.each(function (a) {
                 $('#table1').append('<tr><td>'+$(this).val()+'</td></tr>');
            // $('#table1').append('<tr><td>'+$(this).text()+'</td></tr>');
            //if you need ah text like days do with that
            });
        }
    });
```

```css
table,tr,td{
  border:1px solid red;
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="form-box form-box-default">Jquery Dropdown List with Max 2 select</h2>
        <select class="limitedNumbChosen" multiple="true">
            <option value="1">Monday</option>
            <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
            <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
            <option value="4">Thursday</option>
            <option value="5">Friday</option>
            <option value="6">Saturday</option>
            <option value="7">Sunday</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="Get Values" class="submit1" id="submit1" />
        <table id="table1">
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Missed out prefix `#` for the id `table1`

```
$('#table1').append('<tr><td>'+$(this).val() +'</td></tr>');
```

Comment: Oh sorry Thank you for your response. I got error saying that selected.each is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Change code like this.

```
 var selected = $('.limitedNumbChosen :selected').text().split(",");
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes all selected values should split by comma but above piece of code is not working. If i select monday and tuesday it shows me mondaytuesday.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `text` function, use the correct selector for the table

```
var selected = $('.limitedNumbChosen :selected');
    selected.each(function () {
        $('#table1').append('<tr><td>'+$(this).val() +'</td></tr>');
    });
```

or :

```
 var selected = $('.limitedNumbChosen :selected');
        selected.each(function () {
            $('#table1').append('<tr><td>'+$(this).text() +'</td></tr>');
        });
```

if you want to return the weekdays

Answer (score 1):

You can get it working by using slightly different selector for `select` element, and like mentioned by Sudharsan S changing the selector for table to `#table1`:

```
 var selected = $('.limitedNumbChosen');
```

workable code and [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/2thmy9vf/2/)

```
$("#submit1").click(function() {
  {
    var selected = $('.limitedNumbChosen');
    selected.each(function() {
      $('#table1').append('<tr><td>' + $(this).val() + '</td></tr>');
    });
  }
});
```